# Can Gandalf's jewel conversion ability be used more than once per turn?

Tags: the-hobbit-enchanted-gold

In *[The Hobbit: Enchanted Gold](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/159044/hobbit-enchanted-gold)*, Gandalf's ability is as follows:

> When you play the Gandalf card, you may (optionally) replace any one jewel required on an Encounter card with two jewels of any other colour – but they must be of the same colour. The jewels may come from your supply and/or from bonus jewels on your defeated encounter cards.

This sounds like you can only use the ability once per turn, since it is "any one jewel". However, the example of play has it being used twice:

> You can use Gandalf's special effect to play 2 red jewels instead of 1 of the required 2 purple ones on the Bolg card.
>
> With Gandalf's help (again) you can use the blue jewel in your supply and the blue bonus jewel on the Orcs card instead of the 2nd purple jewel.

Which is correct? The rules or the example of play?